# web Grid column to pass style class

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, webgrid, mvcgrid

I have defined my grid column as below,

```
WebGridColumn colRequestorEmail= new WebGridColumn();
colRequestorEmail.ColumnName = "RequestorEmail";
colRequestorEmail.Header = "Requestor Email Id";
colRequestorEmail.CanSort = true;
colRequestorEmail.Style = "name";
```

and my CSS as below,

```
.name { width: 0px;visibility: hidden; }
```

I am still able to see the column that I want to pass as hidden?

Comment: Do you want to hide a particular column in web grid?

Answer (score -1):

you add a css name here and set the actual attribute with your css file

```
  // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the CSS class attribute that is rendered as part of the HTML table
    //     cells that are associated with the System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid column.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The CSS class attribute that is applied to cells that are associated with the
    //     column.
```